# Setting kartik switch input true and false value

Tags: yii2, yii2-extension

Am using **yii2** kartik switch input and I would like to set the switch input true and false value explicitly

This is the switch input

```
<?php

echo $form->field($model, 'PR_Status_ID')->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [])->label(false);;
    ?>
```

Am using the switch input for updating a field and i would like the switch input to be off if the value of `$model PR_Status_ID` is **6** and on if the value is **7**

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the initial value based on the `PR_Status_ID` field for update case:

```
    echo $form->field($model, 'PR_Status_ID')->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [
         'value' => (!$model->isNewRecord && $model->PR_Status_ID == 6) ? false : true,
    ])->label(false);
```